# Change LANDSCAPE Jasper report to PORTRAIT when export pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want only PORTRAIT pdf but my code not change my landscape jasper report. How to fix it? or rotate my landscape jasper.

```
String output = "report.pdf";
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
JasperPrint portraitPage = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport1, parameters1, conn);
JasperPrint landscapePage = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport2, parameters2, conn);

landscapePage.setOrientation(OrientationEnum.PORTRAIT);

jasperPrintList.add(portraitPage); 
jasperPrintList.add(landscapePage ); 

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperPrintList);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, new FileOutputStream(output));
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: What is the design layout of landscape jasper report? is it landscape or portrait

Comment: it is landscape.